# Creating a UIStackView with percentage values for distribution

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uistackview

I am attempting to create a custom `UIStackView` function that takes in percentage values to fill the axis bounds. I am struggling to implement this properly. I have tried a few things but it is not working properly. Is there a way I can implement this? Or is there already a way to do it built in?

```
extension UIStackView {

    func setHeightPercentageFill(values: [CGFloat]) {
        guard values.count == arrangedSubviews.count else { return }
        axis = .vertical
        distribution = .fillProportionally
        for i in 0..<arrangedSubviews.count {
            arrangedSubviews[i].heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: bounds.height * values[i]).isActive = true
        }
    }
}
```

Desired Usage (To set heights to 20%, 40%, 30%, 10% for each of the subviews)

```
let stack = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [view1, view2, view3, view4])
addSubview(stack)
stack.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
stack.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor).isActive = true
stack.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leftAnchor).isActive = true
stack.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor).isActive = true
stack.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: rightAnchor).isActive = true

stack.setHeightPercentageFill(values: [0.20, 0.40, 0.30, 0.10])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code isn't working because a stackView's size depends on it's subviews' intrinsic content size. You have a chicken/egg scenario. The stackView's height depends on the height of the subviews, and the subviews height depends on the stackView's height. You need to tell the stackView what you want the height to be.

Passing the height to `setHeightPercentageFill(values:)` works for me:

```
extension UIStackView {
    func setHeightPercentageFill(values: [CGFloat], height: CGFloat) {
        guard values.count == arrangedSubviews.count else { return }
        axis = .vertical
        distribution = .fillProportionally
        for i in 0..<arrangedSubviews.count {
            arrangedSubviews[i].heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: height * values[i]).isActive = true
        }
    }
}
```

Note that I define the container height as 128 in the storyboard. You need to make sure that whichever view you constrain your stackView to has a fixed height.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    lazy var view1: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.backgroundColor = .red
        return view
    }()

    lazy var view2: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.backgroundColor = .orange
        return view
    }()

    lazy var view3: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.backgroundColor = .blue
        return view
    }()

    lazy var view4: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.backgroundColor = .yellow
        return view
    }()

    @IBOutlet weak var container: UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let stack = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [view1, view2, view3, view4])
        container.addSubview(stack)
        stack.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        stack.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: container.topAnchor).isActive = true
        stack.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: container.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        stack.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: container.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        stack.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: container.rightAnchor).isActive = true

        stack.setHeightPercentageFill(values: [0.20, 0.40, 0.30, 0.10], height: container.frame.size.height)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are various approaches to this task. You may find this one a little more flexible...

Instead of calling a func to calculate explicit values, you can set the height constraints of the arranged subviews to a percentage of the height of the stack view.

Couple advantages:

- when the stack view's frame changes, perhaps on device rotation, no need to re-calculate anything
- you can control the total height of the stack view either by constraining it (with .heightAnchor or .bottomAnchor) ***or*** by setting the height of one of the arranged subviews
- if the stack view height is not constant, you can reliably set the constraints in `viewDidLoad()` without having to wait for auto-layout to determine the height of the stack view

Here's a complete example - it will print the heights of the arrangedSubviews to debug console, both on `viewDidAppear()` and on `viewWillTransition(to size:...)` to confirm:

```
extension UIStackView {
    func setHeightPercentageFill(values: [CGFloat]) {
        guard values.count == arrangedSubviews.count else { return }
        axis = .vertical
        spacing = 0
        distribution = .fill
        for i in 0..<arrangedSubviews.count {
            arrangedSubviews[i].heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: heightAnchor, multiplier: values[i]).isActive = true
        }
    }
}

class StackPercentViewController: UIViewController {

    let stack: UIStackView = {
        let v = UIStackView()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return v
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let colors: [UIColor] = [.red, .green, .blue, .yellow]

        colors.forEach {
            let v = UIView()
            v.backgroundColor = $0
            stack.addArrangedSubview(v)
        }

        view.addSubview(stack)

        // respect safe area
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([

            // constrain stack view Top / Leading / Trailing at 40-pts
            stack.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 40.0),
            stack.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 40.0),
            stack.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -40.0),

        ])

        // change "if true" to "if false" to test giving the stack view a height
        if true {
            // either give one arranged subview a height constraint
            if let v = stack.arrangedSubviews.first {
                v.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 20.0).isActive = true
            }
        } else {
            // or, constrain the stack view's height (.heightAnchor or .bottomAnchor)
            stack.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor, constant: -40.0).isActive = true
            //stack.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200.0).isActive = true
        }

        stack.setHeightPercentageFill(values: [0.20, 0.40, 0.30, 0.10])

    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        checkHeights()
    }

    override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
        super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)
        coordinator.animate(alongsideTransition: nil, completion: {
            _ in
            self.checkHeights()
        })
    }

    func checkHeights() {
        // print heights of arrangedSubviews to debug console
        stack.arrangedSubviews.forEach {
            print($0.frame.size.height)
        }
        print() // blank line in console
    }

}
```

Results...

With ***first subview height*** constrained to 20:

[image]
[image]

With ***stack view height*** constrained to 200:

[image]
[image]

With ***stack view*** constrained to 40-pts on all 4 sides:

[image]
[image]